# Git rename and abandon a branch

Tags: git

There is a series of commits on a main branch, pushed to remote. At some point work started off of one of the previous commits without creating a branch. I don't want to keep any changes from C and D. It seems a merge with "strategy ours" would still add unwanted new files from the previous series.

```
 A --- B --- C --- D     origin/master
       `-- E --- F       master
```

How to:

- keep C and D but not on a master branch.
- close D for any further commits.
- F becomes a tip of master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps will "save" commits `C` and `D`, and update `origin/master` with `master` without commits `C` and `D`.

1. Checkout `D`
2. Give `D` a branch name, `git branch <my-branch-name>`
3. Checkout `master`
4. Force push `master`, `git push --force-with-lease`

If you don't want to "save" commits `C` or `D`, just skip to step 3.

---

**CAUTION: Force push can cause problems with contributors repos.
[See here for more information on the topic](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/).**